# In Influxdb, I cannot retrieve correct values in time range

Tags: docker, influxdb

I have an influx database runngin in a docker and populated with values using the command `influx -import -path="path/to/txt/file.txt" -precision=n` from a text file.

Here is the text file:

```
apikey,apiKey=master_key_4,param=client5 count=45 1482544000000000000
apikey,apiKey=master_key_4,param=client5 count=85 1482562800000000000
apikey,apiKey=master_key_4,param=client5 count=574 1482889600000000000
apikey,apiKey=master_key_4,param=client5 count=567 1482966000000000000
```

There are 4 values, the first two are values from the 24th of December 2016, the third from the 28th and the fourth from the 29th.

Then I execute a query in order to find all the values between november 30th and december 31th and expect to retrieve all the values I entered previously. Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT * FROM apikey WHERE apiKey = 'master_key_4' AND time >= '2016-11-30 23:59:59.999' AND time <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59.999' GROUP BY param order by time
```

The thing is that I'm not able to retrieve the last two values even if they are included in the time range I gave:

```
name: apikey
tags: param=client5
time                    apiKey          count
----                    ------          -----
1482544000000000000     master_key_4    45
1482562800000000000     master_key_4    85
```

Comment: Currently I am able to reproduce this issue with completly different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, it has nothing to do with the fact that the database is contained in a docker.

Actually the problem does come from the version 1.2 of InfluxDB

I tested with verison 0.13, 1.0 and 1.1 of Influx and everything works perfectly, I cannot reproduce the issue. Downgrading the version could be a workaround if you encounter the same problem.